# Is it possible to use ng-value and ng-model at the same time?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to use ng-value and ng-model at the same time?
I find this code on W3school
https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_ng-value
I try to add `ng-model="showVar"` on the input text and add `{{showVar}}` on the html.
but when I run the html. the `{{showVar}}` did not show the `Hello World!!!`....., any idea??Thx....

[image]

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input ng-value="myVar" ng-model="showVar">
    {{showVar}}
    </div>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.myVar = "Hello World!";
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: can someone explain why these two answers say the opposite ? which one is correct? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47846342/is-it-possible-to-use-ng-value-and-ng-model-at-the-same-time    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52699583/why-cant-we-use-ngmodel-and-value-in-same-input-tag-in-angular-6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mismatch between your variable names.  You are using both `showVar` and `myVar`. Try this:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<input ng-value="myVar" ng-model="myVar">
{{myVar}}
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myVar = "Hello World!";
});
</script>
```

Comment: can someone explain why these two answers say the opposite ? which one is correct? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47846342/is-it-possible-to-use-ng-value-and-ng-model-at-the-same-time    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52699583/why-cant-we-use-ngmodel-and-value-in-same-input-tag-in-angular-6

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use.check the angular documentation for more details
[ngValue angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue)

Answer (score 0):

Hi data will bind using ng-model .so  `$scope.myVar = "Hello World!";` its wrong. it would be your model name like  `$scope.showVar = "Hello World!";`