# Why can't we use [(ngModel)] and value in same input tag in angular 6

Tags: html, angular, angular6, model-binding

My html tag is:

```
<input matInput placeholder="Vehicle Number" name="vehicleNo" [(ngModel)]="vehicleNo" value="vehicle.vehicleNo" >
```

I need to automatically fill the input field and if i enter new thing it need to access in component.ts file.

Comment: In your case ngmodel will work for you. Why do you need to use value then. ngmodel can bind the value though.

Comment: but i can't access that value in component.ts file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In angular if you are using ngModel to bind data then you don't need to use value attribute, it will automatically bind the data.

//in ts file

```
export className extends OnInit{
    vehicle: any;

    ngOnInit(){

       this.serviceName.functionName().subscribe(
           data=>{
               this.vehicle=data;
           }error=>{
               //whatever logic you want to place
          }
      );
   }
}
```

//in html file

```
<input matInput placeholder="Vehicle Number" name="vehicleNo" [(ngModel)]="vehicle.vehicleNo">
```

// if you are defining it this way `vehicleObj = { vehicleNo:this.vehicleNo }`

then html file should be

```
<input matInput placeholder="Vehicle Number" name="vehicleNo" [(ngModel)]="vehicleObj .vehicleNo">
```

Comment: But i can't access that value in component.ts file. It shows the variable is undefined

Comment: how are you accessing the data?

Comment: vehicleNo:this.vehicleNo

Comment: export class UpdateVehiclePopup {
  vehicleNo: String;
  
  constructor(
    private updVehicles:VehicleServiceService
  ) { 
  };
  updateVehicle(){
    const vehicleObj = { 
      vehicleNo:this.vehicleNo
    }
    console.log(vehicleObj);
  }
}

Comment: Check the code now. I have given you a general scenario and whatever you are doing also.

Comment: can someone explain why these two answers say the opposite ? which one is correct? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47846342/is-it-possible-to-use-ng-value-and-ng-model-at-the-same-time    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52699583/why-cant-we-use-ngmodel-and-value-in-same-input-tag-in-angular-6

Answer (score 0):

this expression will not evaluate as javascript expression `value="vehicle.vehicle No"` this how you do property binding `[value]="vehicle.vehicle No"`

just set `vehicleNo` to `vehicle.vehicleNo` and the input will updated you don't need to do't by yourself this what ngModel made for .